# Drupal notification emails not getting sent

Tags: drupal, notifications, messaging

I'm using the notifications module to notify users when comments are added. However, I've tested it and the emails aren't being sent out. When I try to process the notification queue, I'm getting the following error:

> user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type for db_type_placeholder AND send_interval = unsupported type for db_type_pl' at line 1 query: SELECT * FROM notifications_queue WHERE cron = unsupported type for db_type_placeholder AND send_interval
>   = unsupported type for db_type_placeholder ORDER BY module, uid, destination, send_method, send_interval in /home/openupor/public_html/sites/default/modules/notifications/notifications.cron.inc on line 210.

Can anyone tell me how I can go about troubleshooting this? I've had a look at line 210 but this isn't helping me. I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal uses a placeholder system to safely insert variables into SQL without the risk of SQL injection.

example:

```
$nid = 100;
db_query("SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE nid = %d;", $nid);
```

will produce the query:

```
SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE nid = 100;
```

Now From the error messages, it looks like the variable that was attempted to be inserted into  the query was an unsupported type, like fx `stdClass`. So the best place to start is to look at what is generating these variables.

You should search the module's issue log to see if other have had this issue and if not, post a bug report. It might not be a bug in notefication, but the module maintainer might be able to give you some fast answers or advice on how to proceed, and it can help others in the same situation.

Comment: Hi Googletorp, thank you for your response. I took this website over from someone else and so I think they may have customised the code. Where would I need to look to find out what is generating these variables?

Comment: @Ben: First thing to do, is to make sure you are running non altered code. Bite the bullet, upgrade modules/core and see what breaks, if there have been done alterations. Then you can take it from there, that is the only sensible solution. Trying to maintain a undocumented hacked core is not a way to run a drupal site.